# Auto replacement of subject line in inbound Outlook emails

Tags: outlook-2003, email-headers

I need to replace the contents of the subject line of all incoming email (whatever it maybe ) with "EBIT Support" and that same mail then forwarded to the new and correct inbox- an ideas vey welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for VBA code. Do you have any code written at all?

I have some stock event code that can be adapted for your purposes:

http://www.codeforexcelandoutlook.com/outlook-vba/stock-event-code/

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
' (1) default Inbox
Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

On Error Goto ErrorHandler

  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem

  ' (2) only act if it's a MailItem
  If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set Msg = item

    ' (3) do something here

  End If

ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```